# Using function compositions to determine variable values

Tags: discrete-mathematics, function-and-relation-composition, inverse-function

Let $f,g:$ $R \rightarrow R$ where $g(x)$ $=$ $1$ $-$ $x$ $+$ $x^2$ and $f(x)$ $=$ $ax$ $+$ $b$

If $g(f(x))$ $=$ $9x^2$ $-$ $9x$ $+$ $3$, determine $a$ and $b$.

So far, I have "fit" $f(x)$ into $g(x)$ as follows: $g(f(x))$ $=$ $(ax + b)^2$ $-$ $(ax+b)$ $+$ $1$

Is there a relationship between compositions and inverse functions I should be using to isolate $a$ and $b$? How does one extract those variables in order to determine their value?

Thank you!

Comment: Coefficients by the degrees of $x$ must be the same. So after expansion you'd have a system of equations to solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky do I need to start by FOIL-ing out the $(ax + b)^2$?

Comment: You need to give the latter expression the same form as the former. But in this case the coefficients will be not a concrete numbers but an expressions on the unknowns. In particular, you don't need inverse.

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky when you say "latter," are you referring to f(x)? I need to make f(x) the same form as g(x)?

Comment: No. I meant the equation. Here you have two, one is $g(f(x)) = 9x^2 − 9x + 3$, the other is $g(f(x)) = \alpha(a, b)x^2 + \beta(a, b)x + \gamma(a, b)$. And you also know the expressions for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ and their values on the given $a$ and $b$.

Comment: General idea is that if you have equality of polynomials (over $x$), $p + qx + rx^2 + \dots = p' + q'x + r'x^2 + \dots$, then you have $p = p'$, $q = q'$, $r = r'$, etc.

Answer (score 2):

First expand the expression and regroup the components.

$$g(f(x)) = 1 − (ax+b) + (ax+b)^2$$

$$g(f(x)) = 1 − ax − b + a^2x^2 + 2abx + b^2$$

$$g(f(x)) = (1 − b + b^2) + a(2b − 1)x + a^2x^2$$

We know that

$$g(f(x)) = 3 − 9x + 9x^2$$

Therefore

$$(1 − b + b^2) + a(2b − 1)x + a^2x^2 = 3 − 9x + 9x^2$$

The system to solve is

$$a^2=9$$

$$a(2b − 1)=−9$$

$$1 − b + b^2=3$$

So $a = \pm 3$, then

- if $a = 3$, then $b = -1$, and the last equation does not satisfy
- if $a = -3$, then $b = 2$, and the last equation does satisfy.

Finally, the solution is $a = -3$, $b = 2$.